# Why .attr does not change the attribute in each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attr

I have a very simple script that should change links' `id`s but somehow it is not working. Here is the code :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('mylinks').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': 'mylink-'+index
        });
    });
});


<div class="mylinks">
<a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">google2</a>
</div>
```

I have tries changing `mylinks` to :

- `div.mylinks`
- `div.mylinks a`

but none of them worked. What am I missing ?

**EDIT**

Most of you are right. I have to use `$('.mylinks a').each( ...` but the issue was that I was looking at the `RMB`->`Source` (where the content is not updated) instead of `Inspect Element`.

Comment: FYI, it's better to do `this.id = 'mylink-'+index` instead of using `.attr()`. Much cleaner, shorter, faster code that way.

Comment: ...or if you do use the `.attr()` method, use it to eliminate your `.each()` call, like this... `$('.mylinks a').attr('id', function(i) { return 'mylink-'+i; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your code and change this:

```
$('.mylinks a')
```

Comment: That (before you edited it) will match the div, not the links

Answer (score 4):

The selector `mylinks` matches every `<mylinks>` element on the page.

To match `<a>` elements that are descendants of a member of the *mylinks* class you need `.mylinks a`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code refers to the div, not the links. Oh, and you left out the period before mylinks to properly denote the class of the div.

`$('mylinks').each(` should be `$('.mylinks a').each(`

Here's a **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZhWSa/)**.

```
$('.mylinks a').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr({
        'id': 'mylink-' + index
    });
});​
```

Comment: That (before you edited it) will match `<mylinks><a /></mylinks>`, which doesn't exist in HTML.

Comment: @Quentin - Yup, I caught that (gotta love the edit link). My fingers were flying over my keyboard so fast I'm lucky I didn't make other typos.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.mylinks a').each(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is incorrect for mylinks. It should be `$('.mylinks a').each()`

Answer (score 2):

`class` selector starts with `.` . change the code as below

```
$('.mylinks a').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'mylink-'+index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If `mylinks` is the class that you give to your link, then you should write `$('.mylinks')`

Comment: It isn't. *mylinks* is the class of a container.

Comment: Then use `$('.mylinks').find('a')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it to look at the links, not just the div. This works:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.mylinks a').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr("id", "mylinks"+index);
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, there's a convinience utility you can use to shorten the document.ready format, like this: __$(function() { });__

Answer (score 0):

`$('mylinks')` will look for element with tag name `mylinks`. May be its a typo you should use `.` for class selector. If you want to select all the anchor elements inside `.mylinks` and set there ids then use this.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.mylinks a').each(function(index) {
        $(this).attr({
            'id': 'mylink-'+index
        });
    });
});
```